# Stored procedure with output / input parameters return count

Tags: c#, sql

I want to get the value returned from a stored procedure. I execute in SQL and everything works fine, but when called from C# I get 0.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USerFilter_SP_MatchUserFilter](
@User varchar(50), 
@Car varchar(50), 
@Part varchar(50), 
@State varchar(50), 
@Year varchar(50) )
AS 
Begin
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(

    /* Statement here request row count */

)X
End
```

Comment: If the problem only occurs when calling it from your application, you should probably show us the code you're using ..

Comment: My psychic powers tell me you're using `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting NOCOUNT on:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms189837.aspx

What I think you'll see happening is the the 'messages' window in SSMS that you are getting a row count returns for the inner query. This can stuff up C# a little bit. SET NOCOUNT ON suppresses that so you are only returning the good stuff:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USerFilter_SP_MatchUserFilter](
  @User varchar(50), 
  @Car varchar(50), 
  @Part varchar(50), 
  @State varchar(50), 
  @Year varchar(50) )
AS 
Begin

   -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
   -- interfering with SELECT statements.
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM
   (
       /* Statement here request row count */
   )X
End
```